# Callback paramter recieves with blank spaces at reciever end

Tags: javascript, ajax, base64

**Description:**

I'm encountering an issue with the "Callback" parameter sent in the header of an AJAX request. The problem is intermittent—sometimes the parameter is received perfectly, but other times it contains white spaces or appears broken at the "/" character.

Here's the relevant code snippet:

```js
$.ajax({
    url: "https://example.com/api/endpoint",
    type: "GET",
    headers: {
        "Callback": "cfwJI63/lsmRh5mmRG/E7uR0hWyRqPLYAKiqkWtToIi8b7/kw5QkZvwhgd4nhSMxqnPtysWg9MtIRTXXY5FRv2VYmfytFvs25hgzWwijPE05Re6ox8DE9IYgCydL9V51cAYks5kmdkqSLThbFSasv5aC4ZaurmDD/nra7E9jGc3VO0z8TrgTFBop0AlwdrPzIBisnRqF+Kw2o9yKvAArSdUPjgwSBSrSC/uSVdfhDFb1UiQv5G1eR9sV4/GKP1+VMVdyftiKYGll4YDbgxI+4scQfa/FIC3VkYtpoLXuG+hXFls0o22Xd4PBPx9MDM/e9YsteFC4v1mdd5eReD6X8Q==",
        // Other headers...
    },
    success: function(resp) { 
        console.log(resp);
        $("#page_holder").html(resp);
    }
});
```